# What are these ports on a 20th anniversary Mac?

Tags: mac

Yesterday I found a Twentieth Anniversary Mac in my Nonna's basement. Apparently it's been there since 2002. I was very curious about this and I Googled it and found that it was a special edition.

On the rear and side are some ports I'm not familiar with. I wonder if anyone can explain them?

The rear has 6 ports and I don't know what ports 3, 4, and 5 are for? There's also a large port on the left hand side that I'm not familiar with.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You probably should add a picture of these ports

Comment: Google it yet??

Comment: Here are the specs: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/20th_mac/specs/20th-anniversary-mac.html#macspecs2

Comment: It may help if you add a photo of the ports

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, that's a find!

Actually, there are more than six ports on the rear, there's also a cover you can open to reveal a whole heap of other ports (e.g. Serial ports, ADB port, etc).

However, to explain the ports in your question:

- Port 3 is a SCSI port
- Port 4 is a TV Tuner port
- Port 5 is a FM radio port
- the port on the left side you refer to is a PCI slot (Note there's actually a comm slot above this as well).

Below are some images I've taken from the Twentieth Anniversary Mac Service Source:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

This model actually has a switch to select the appropriate voltage for your country (see below), so make sure you have the correct voltage selected for your location.

[image]

If your location is not listed, then select whichever is appropriate (e.g. if you're in Australia then select 230v).

**[EDIT]**

Finally, as per IconDaemon's comment below, you can access the service documentation [directly](http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/legacy/twentieth_anniversary_mac.pdf) for yourself.

Comment: Mac Service Source document (from which the illustrations above were sourced) can be found [at this link](http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/legacy/twentieth_anniversary_mac.pdf). Easily found on the Googles.

Comment: @IconDaemon Nice find! You can even [access service manuals](http://www.tim.id.au/blog/tims-laptop-service-manuals/) for a whole heap of other laptops too! - But I'm guessing you already knew that! I'll update my answer to include a direct link to the Twentieth Anniversary Mac doc. Thanks for the heads up! :)